# Why does Spacy's NER trainer return tokens but not entities?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

Thanks for looking.  I am trying to train a custom Named Entity Recognizer, using code from Spacy's website.  My problem is that after I run my examples through the trainer, it returns the tokens, but no entities.  Here are my examples, saved in the variable `to_train_ents`:

```py
[('"We’re at the beginning of what we could do with laser ultrasound," says Brian W. Anthony, a principal research scientist in MIT’s Department of Mechanical Engineering and Institute for Medical Engineering and Science (IMES), a senior author on the paper.',
  {'entities': [(72, 88, 'PERSON')]}),
 ('Early concepts for noncontact laser ultrasound for medical imaging originated from a Lincoln Laboratory program established by Rob Haupt of the Active Optical Systems Group and Chuck Wynn of the Advanced Capabilities and Technologies Group, who are co-authors on the new paper along with Matthew Johnson.',
  {'entities': [(126, 135, 'PERSON'),
    (176, 186, 'PERSON'),
    (287, 302, 'PERSON')]}),
 ('From there, the research grew via collaboration with Anthony and his students, Xiang (Shawn) Zhang, who is now an MIT postdoc and is the paper’s first author, and recent doctoral graduate Jonathan Fincke, who is also a co-author.',
  {'entities': [(78, 97, 'PERSON'), (187, 202, 'PERSON')]})]
```

From what I can tell, they are formatted correctly to pass into the trainer.  Here is the code used to train the NER model, from spacy.io:

```py
def main(model = None, output_dir = None, n_iter = 100):
    # Load the model, set up the pipeline and train the entity recognizer
    if model is not None:   # If model was specified...
        nlp = spacy.load(model)   # ...load the existing spaCy model
        pprint("Loaded model '%s'" % model)
    else:
        nlp = spacy.blank("en")   # ...otherwise, create a blank language class
        print("Created blank 'en' model")

    # Create the built-in pipeline components and add them to the pipeline
    # nlp.create_pipe works for built-ins that are registered with spaCy
    if "ner" not in nlp.pipe_names:   # If Named Entity Recognition is not part of the pipeline...
        ner = nlp.create_pipe("ner")
        nlp.add_pipe(ner, last = True)   # ...add it to the pipeline
    else:
        ner = nlp.get_pipe("ner")

    # Add labels
    for _, annotations in to_train_ents:
        for ent in annotations.get("entities"):  # "get" is a way of retrieving items from dictionaries
            ner.add_label(ent[2])

    # Get names of other pipes to disable them during training (we want only NER)
    other_pipes = [pipe for pipe in nlp.pipe_names if pipe != "ner"] # other_pipes is any pipe that is not NER
    with nlp.disable_pipes(*other_pipes):  # Train only NER
        # Reset and initialize the weights randomly - but only if we're training a new model
        if model is None:
            nlp.begin_training()
        for itn in range(n_iter):
            random.shuffle(to_train_ents)
            losses = {}
            # Batch up the examples using spaCy's minibatch
            batches = minibatch(to_train_ents, size = compounding(4.0, 32.0, 1.001))
            for batch in batches:
                texts, annotations = zip(*batch)
                nlp.update(
                texts,  # Batch of texts
                annotations,  # Batch of annotations
                drop = 0.5,  # Dropout - make it harder to memorize data (adjustable variable)
                losses = losses,
                )
            print("Losses", losses)

    # Test the trained model
    for text, _ in to_train_ents:
        doc = nlp(text)
        print("Entities", [(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])
        print("Tokens", [(t.text, t.ent_type_, t.ent_iob) for t in doc])

    # Save the model to output directory
    if output_dir is not None:
        output_dir = Path(output_dir)
        if not output_dir.exists():
            output_dir.mkdir()
        nlp.to_disk(output_dir)
        print("Saved model to", output_dir)

    # Test the saved model
    print("Loading from", output_dir)
    nlp2 = spacy.load(output_dir)
    for text, _ in to_train_ents:
        doc = nlp2(text)
        print("Entities", [(ent.text, ent.label_) for ent in doc.ents])
        print("Tokens", [(t.text, t.ent_type_, t.ent_iob) for t in doc])
```

I tell this function to use the english model and to save in output directory 'nih_ner':

```py
main(model = 'en', output_dir = 'nih_ner')
```

Here is the result:

```
"Loaded model 'en'"
Losses {'ner': 52.71057402440056}
Losses {'ner': 43.944127584481976}
Losses {'ner': 40.92080506101935}
~snip~
Losses {'ner': 8.647840025578502}
Losses {'ner': 0.001753763942560257}
Entities []
Tokens [('From', '', 2), ('there', '', 2), (',', '', 2), ('the', '', 2), ('research', '', 2), ('grew', '', 2), ('via', '', 2), ('collaboration', '', 2), ('with', '', 2), ('Anthony', '', 2), ('and', '', 2), ('his', '', 2), ('students', '', 2), (',', '', 2), ('Xiang', '', 2), ('(', '', 2), ('Shawn', '', 2), (')', '', 2), ('Zhang', '', 2), (',', '', 2), ('who', '', 2), ('is', '', 2), ('now', '', 2), ('an', '', 2), ('MIT', '', 2), ('postdoc', '', 2), ('and', '', 2), ('is', '', 2), ('the', '', 2), ('paper', '', 2), ('’s', '', 2), ('first', '', 2), ('author', '', 2), (',', '', 2), ('and', '', 2), ('recent', '', 2), ('doctoral', '', 2), ('graduate', '', 2), ('Jonathan', '', 2), ('Fincke', '', 2), (',', '', 2), ('who', '', 2), ('is', '', 2), ('also', '', 2), ('a', '', 2), ('co', '', 2), ('-', '', 2), ('author', '', 2), ('.', '', 2)]
Entities []
Tokens [('"', '', 2), ('We', '', 2), ('’re', '', 2), ('at', '', 2), ('the', '', 2), ('beginning', '', 2), ('of', '', 2), ('what', '', 2), ('we', '', 2), ('could', '', 2), ('do', '', 2), ('with', '', 2), ('laser', '', 2), ('ultrasound', '', 2), (',', '', 2), ('"', '', 2), ('says', '', 2), ('Brian', '', 2), ('W.', '', 2), ('Anthony', '', 2), (',', '', 2), ('a', '', 2), ('principal', '', 2), ('research', '', 2), ('scientist', '', 2), ('in', '', 2), ('MIT', '', 2), ('’s', '', 2), ('Department', '', 2), ('of', '', 2), ('Mechanical', '', 2), ('Engineering', '', 2), ('and', '', 2), ('Institute', '', 2), ('for', '', 2), ('Medical', '', 2), ('Engineering', '', 2), ('and', '', 2), ('Science', '', 2), ('(', '', 2), ('IMES', '', 2), (')', '', 2), (',', '', 2), ('a', '', 2), ('senior', '', 2), ('author', '', 2), ('on', '', 2), ('the', '', 2), ('paper', '', 2), ('.', '', 2)]
Entities []
Tokens [('Early', '', 2), ('concepts', '', 2), ('for', '', 2), ('noncontact', '', 2), ('laser', '', 2), ('ultrasound', '', 2), ('for', '', 2), ('medical', '', 2), ('imaging', '', 2), ('originated', '', 2), ('from', '', 2), ('a', '', 2), ('Lincoln', '', 2), ('Laboratory', '', 2), ('program', '', 2), ('established', '', 2), ('by', '', 2), ('Rob', '', 2), ('Haupt', '', 2), ('of', '', 2), ('the', '', 2), ('Active', '', 2), ('Optical', '', 2), ('Systems', '', 2), ('Group', '', 2), ('and', '', 2), ('Chuck', '', 2), ('Wynn', '', 2), ('of', '', 2), ('the', '', 2), ('Advanced', '', 2), ('Capabilities', '', 2), ('and', '', 2), ('Technologies', '', 2), ('Group', '', 2), (',', '', 2), ('who', '', 2), ('are', '', 2), ('co', '', 2), ('-', '', 2), ('authors', '', 2), ('on', '', 2), ('the', '', 2), ('new', '', 2), ('paper', '', 2), ('along', '', 2), ('with', '', 2), ('Matthew', '', 2), ('Johnson', '', 2), ('.', '', 2)]
Saved model to nih_ner
Loading from nih_ner
Entities []
Tokens [('From', '', 2), ('there', '', 2), (',', '', 2), ('the', '', 2), ('research', '', 2), ('grew', '', 2), ('via', '', 2), ('collaboration', '', 2), ('with', '', 2), ('Anthony', '', 2), ('and', '', 2), ('his', '', 2), ('students', '', 2), (',', '', 2), ('Xiang', '', 2), ('(', '', 2), ('Shawn', '', 2), (')', '', 2), ('Zhang', '', 2), (',', '', 2), ('who', '', 2), ('is', '', 2), ('now', '', 2), ('an', '', 2), ('MIT', '', 2), ('postdoc', '', 2), ('and', '', 2), ('is', '', 2), ('the', '', 2), ('paper', '', 2), ('’s', '', 2), ('first', '', 2), ('author', '', 2), (',', '', 2), ('and', '', 2), ('recent', '', 2), ('doctoral', '', 2), ('graduate', '', 2), ('Jonathan', '', 2), ('Fincke', '', 2), (',', '', 2), ('who', '', 2), ('is', '', 2), ('also', '', 2), ('a', '', 2), ('co', '', 2), ('-', '', 2), ('author', '', 2), ('.', '', 2)]
Entities []
Tokens [('"', '', 2), ('We', '', 2), ('’re', '', 2), ('at', '', 2), ('the', '', 2), ('beginning', '', 2), ('of', '', 2), ('what', '', 2), ('we', '', 2), ('could', '', 2), ('do', '', 2), ('with', '', 2), ('laser', '', 2), ('ultrasound', '', 2), (',', '', 2), ('"', '', 2), ('says', '', 2), ('Brian', '', 2), ('W.', '', 2), ('Anthony', '', 2), (',', '', 2), ('a', '', 2), ('principal', '', 2), ('research', '', 2), ('scientist', '', 2), ('in', '', 2), ('MIT', '', 2), ('’s', '', 2), ('Department', '', 2), ('of', '', 2), ('Mechanical', '', 2), ('Engineering', '', 2), ('and', '', 2), ('Institute', '', 2), ('for', '', 2), ('Medical', '', 2), ('Engineering', '', 2), ('and', '', 2), ('Science', '', 2), ('(', '', 2), ('IMES', '', 2), (')', '', 2), (',', '', 2), ('a', '', 2), ('senior', '', 2), ('author', '', 2), ('on', '', 2), ('the', '', 2), ('paper', '', 2), ('.', '', 2)]
Entities []
Tokens [('Early', '', 2), ('concepts', '', 2), ('for', '', 2), ('noncontact', '', 2), ('laser', '', 2), ('ultrasound', '', 2), ('for', '', 2), ('medical', '', 2), ('imaging', '', 2), ('originated', '', 2), ('from', '', 2), ('a', '', 2), ('Lincoln', '', 2), ('Laboratory', '', 2), ('program', '', 2), ('established', '', 2), ('by', '', 2), ('Rob', '', 2), ('Haupt', '', 2), ('of', '', 2), ('the', '', 2), ('Active', '', 2), ('Optical', '', 2), ('Systems', '', 2), ('Group', '', 2), ('and', '', 2), ('Chuck', '', 2), ('Wynn', '', 2), ('of', '', 2), ('the', '', 2), ('Advanced', '', 2), ('Capabilities', '', 2), ('and', '', 2), ('Technologies', '', 2), ('Group', '', 2), (',', '', 2), ('who', '', 2), ('are', '', 2), ('co', '', 2), ('-', '', 2), ('authors', '', 2), ('on', '', 2), ('the', '', 2), ('new', '', 2), ('paper', '', 2), ('along', '', 2), ('with', '', 2), ('Matthew', '', 2), ('Johnson', '', 2), ('.', '', 2)]
```

As you can see, the model returns the tokens to me, but there are empty lists, [], where the recognized entities should be.  Any suggestions as to why this is happening would be helpful.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the *start* and *end* character indices in your training data.
[Zero-based numbering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-based_numbering) must be used and not *1-based numbering*.

With *zero-based numbering* the index of the first character in a string is 0, the index of the second character is 1, etc ..

The following code shows that you offsets are using *1-based numbering*

```
l = []
for a in to_train_ents:
    sentence = a[0]
    for b in a[1]['entities']:
        l.append( sentence[int(b[0]): int(b[1])])
print(l)
# [' Brian W. Anthon', ' Rob Haup', ' Chuck Wyn', ' Matthew Johnso', ' Xiang (Shawn) Zhan', ' Jonathan Finck']
```

Using *zero-based numbering* the training data becomes:

```
to_train_ents = [('"We’re at the beginning of what we could do with laser ultrasound," says Brian W. Anthony, a principal research scientist in MIT’s Department of Mechanical Engineering and Institute for Medical Engineering and Science (IMES), a senior author on the paper.',
  {'entities': [(73, 89, 'PERSON')]}),
 ('Early concepts for noncontact laser ultrasound for medical imaging originated from a Lincoln Laboratory program established by Rob Haupt of the Active Optical Systems Group and Chuck Wynn of the Advanced Capabilities and Technologies Group, who are co-authors on the new paper along with Matthew Johnson.',
  {'entities': [(127, 136, 'PERSON'),
    (177, 187, 'PERSON'),
    (288, 303, 'PERSON')]}),
 ('From there, the research grew via collaboration with Anthony and his students, Xiang (Shawn) Zhang, who is now an MIT postdoc and is the paper’s first author, and recent doctoral graduate Jonathan Fincke, who is also a co-author.',
  {'entities': [(79, 98, 'PERSON'), (188, 203, 'PERSON')]})]
```

Now the model trains and predicts correctly:

```
Losses {'ner': 124.16665458679199}
Losses {'ner': 118.29711055755615}
Losses {'ner': 110.27205085754395}
Losses {'ner': 102.67473244667053}
Losses {'ner': 93.6117731332779}
Losses {'ner': 80.32513558864594}
...
Losses {'ner': 1.56542471502621e-07}
Losses {'ner': 2.071446077606498e-09}
Losses {'ner': 3.4424366409273253e-13}
Losses {'ner': 5.749029666370928e-09}
...
Entities [('Brian W. Anthony', 'PERSON')]
Entities [('Xiang (Shawn) Zhang', 'PERSON'), ('Jonathan Fincke', 'PERSON')]
Entities [('Rob Haupt', 'PERSON'), ('Chuck Wynn', 'PERSON'), ('Matthew Johnson', 'PERSON')]
```

Comment: Fantastic; that was the reason.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: It makes me happy to hear that! Thanks for the feedback :)